# Creating a Loop Within a javasctipt Alert or Prompt

Tags: javascript, loops, alerts

Edit for clarification:

Is there a method to insert code into an alert() or prompt() such as a kind of loop or method of adding data to the alert() or prompt right before running or while running?

-Thanks

Comment: Why can't you create a variable such as `content` and loop before you use the `alert()` and then use `alert(content)`?

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed. Please understand that Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Not sure how else to ask should I delete my post and remake it? I just want a way to create any kind of loop from within a prompt/alert and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Do your loop first

```
for (var n = 0; n<= 50; n++) {varnum1= n*10 - 1;} /*some way to output data tothe alert*/
alert("starting string" + varnum1 + "end of string")
```

Comment: sorry my example doesn't show all cases. I need no limit on the number of varnum1 values to be added to the alert. Even that doesn't matter I want a for loop to take place inside the alert(/* in here*/)

Comment: Your not going to be able to place the loop inside the alert. If you need the logic to take place inside the alert for some reason you could call a function. http://jsfiddle.net/7VUeG/